# How to switch local resource files on event

Tags: c#, asp.net, markup

In my asp.net solution I have generated a local resource file through the Tools -> Generate local resource menu in VS and inside it I changed the text of some controls. I have a dropdownlist that contains the languages I want to be able to switch to (Default.en.aspx.resx for example). How do I code this? How do I refer to a different resource file than the one that is currently active?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically load and switch the resource file in the web app (ASP.NET) without recompiling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649226/how-to-dynamically-load-and-switch-the-resource-file-in-the-web-app-asp-net-wi)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have different languages, including date formatting etc, per user, You could set the CurrentUICulture of the current thread to match the requested language.

For example after someone chooses a language from the dropdown, you could store that in session and then override InitializeCulture on the Page:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    string language = Session["language"].ToString(); // e.g. en-GB
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);
}
```

See [Page.InitializeCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx) and ResourceManager and Culture-Specific Resources in [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx).

Comment: Can't get that code to work:/ I am probably missing something. Does the string passed with GetCultureInfo have anything to do with the naming of the resource file? My file is named Default.aspx.en.resx, does that mean I should pass "en" as "language" in your code sample?

Comment: Yes, the string does matter. As you say, you need to pass "en" or "en-US" or "en-GB" to use Default.aspx.en.resx. If this solution is overkill, does my other answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

To just change specific values, you will need to use the [HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149953.aspx) method to get the text you want. Something like this:

```
string cultureCode = MyDropDown.SelectedValue;

MyLabel.Text = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(
    this.AppRelativeVirtualPath, // virtual path to current page
    "MyLabelText", // key in resx
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureCode) // language
).ToString();
```