# Mvc multilanguage add new language from admin panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created multilanguage wep application with ASP.NET MVC. It's using `app_localsource` with `resx` files.

Aplication like blog web site and some product on it and also some hospitals we hade each table connected to language table. So the data comes from base on their language. If the user click the language all content have to convert the chosen language. E.g. : 'view' button value to 'vue'.

Ex: `global.resx` (default en lang.)
`Global.fr.resx` (for French language)

But I want to add `global.ru.resx` as a file from user which they can edit or add more language as it like that.

Do you have any idea to add new language to that application?

Comment: The type of website you are building makes a huge difference in how this could be implemented. For example, an e-commerce site would need to add multiple languages for each product, but a forum may have a language for each section. This question is too broad to answer as it is, so please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Try reading through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649226/how-to-dynamically-load-and-switch-the-resource-file-in-the-web-app-asp-net-wi and read Luke Karski's answer

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank You..