# ASP.NET MVC : change namespace in web.config under certain conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, web-config

I have in the main `web.config` file under the

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
```

a line that calls for a particular resource

```
<add namespcae="***.resources.male"/>
```

Now I want to change this line to

```
<add namespcae="***.resources.female"/>
```

only if the user is identified as female.

It is possible to check whether the user is male or female through a condition in the `web.config` file?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Seems like you should load both resources and choose to show one set depending on the user...

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem is that there are a lot of pages in the project according to the method you suggest I have to follow this condition for each page.

Comment: Depends on how you use resources. Should be easy enough to write a helper function that takes the resource key and the "male"/"female" string and get the appropriate resource. There are a few questions about dynamically loading resources (e.g., [How to dynamically load and switch the resource file in the web app (ASP.NET) without recompiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1649226/215552) and/or [Getting a string dynamically from strings resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13194293/215552)